# Cinnamon failed: desktop only, no panel, no dialog frame

Tags: linux-mint, x11, cinnamon

I am using Linux Mint 14 (MATE) with Cinnamon installed. Cinnamon failed when I tried to delete an item on the menu with menu editor. The system froze, so I logged out by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

When I logged back in, the desktop panel was not loaded (shortcuts were there as normal, and right-click works as well). I can barely do anyting but get the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. But all the dialogue windows are presented without any frames.

Here are screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I tried reinstalling Cinnamon in the MATE desktop interface (it works fine), but it failed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if your window manager is not running. that is why you do see your window icons. you could run `muffin` from Cinnamon or `Marco` from Mate. That should allow you to move windows and perform normal window operations.

Answer (score 0):

Run mateconf-editor and check that the windowmanager entry under /desktop/mate/session/required_components/ is set to marco.